# N300 Capable wifi, with approriate router, why am I only getting 150kb/s on local transfers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have recently purchased the new Linksys E4200 which quotes Simultaneous Dual Band full N300 speeds.

It should be amazing. Through wired connections, it is amazingly fast. I didn't shell out 300 bucks to get the same network speed my Draft N router achieved 3 years ago.

Basically, I copied a 175MB file across to my media centre pc, both running on wifi, both in the same room as the router. Is it normal for me to only achieve 150kb/s on transferring a file locally?

I was expecting at least 1mb/s.  Is that unreasonable? Or is there some network settings I should be tweaking?

Comment: Definitely not normal, I have a 54Mbps router at home, I get 2MB/sec (megabytes/sec) on average.

Comment: @SevenT2: We need more information about your setup: for instance, do both PC's have Wireless N adapters? What signal strength are they showing? What kind of configuration settings are you using? In particular which networking mode (e.g. Wireless-N Only)? Have you tried changing the wireless channel?

Comment: Also, are you using 2.4GHz or 5GHz? Have you tried disabling the unused band?